# Dynamic navigation in laravel using jquery and bootstrap?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel, I am loving it so far and am trying to utilize the blade templating system as much as possible. What I have right now is my navigation existing in the middle of the screen at the root of the site:

[image]

and inside of my home.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
@parent
    ::Home
@stop

@section('content')

    <div class="row col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center indexWrapper">
        <div class="indexNav">
        <ul class="text-right">
            <li><a href="artists">Artists</a></li>
            <li><a href="bulletin">Bulletin</a></li>
            <li><a href="something">Something</a></li>
            <li><a href="something">Something</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="indexHeading">
            <h1 class="indexH1">Mumbler</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

@stop
```

and my master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
@section('title')
@show
</title>  
<link href="{{ asset('bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/default.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> 
<link href="{{ asset('bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}" rel="script">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @section('navigation')
        @show

        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am also new to Bootstrap, so I apologize for what might be egregious misuse of classes. What I do have though, is a margin of 25% on what wraps this navigation, and when I click on one of the links (I.E. artists), I want that whole navigation to move up (jquery, I can handle that much), and the 'artists' view to appear below. What would be an elegant solution to this? Any resources for a beginner to laravel 4?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should've tagged this as javascript and jquery since blade does not do what you want it to, (move up when someone clicks the link)

Comment: Part of it is that I don't quite know how I should be handling it within blade. I understand the jquery to do it, but where does that go? How should the subsequent view be called within Laravel and how could it appear seamless?